# how can i get a matching string from a xml file using <getxmlproperties> tag using ant and replace the matched string in other xml file

Tags: java, xml, build, ant, devops

My requirement is to match following  tag in data.xml file and replace the content in display.xml file using  in ant

```
data.xml
--------

<data>123456789</data>

display.xml
----------- 

<data>abcdefg</data
```

I need to match the content in data.xml file and replace the it in display.xml file.

my final output should be like:

```
data.xml
--------
<data>123456789</data>

display.xml
-----------
<data>123456789</data>
```

How can i solve this Issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any Ant task named `GetXmlProperties`, but I think you may have thought about this one, [`XmlProperty`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/xmlproperty.html), which composes a sequence of properties from parsing an XML document.

Two ways, to achieve what you want, come to my mind (there may be more):

1. The most primitive would be to just use the `XmlProperty` task to retreive the value in question and use a crude `Replace` task on the destination file, doing a simple string replace, by handling the destination as a plain text file, instead of caring for the XML logic in it. However, doing string match and replace with XML data is no fun and error prone.
2. Thus I propose a second approach, which is to use the [`XmlTask`](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/), as per the following example. Adding a prefix `xml` to our newly parsed properties makes it easier to distinguish them from the rest. For demo purposes we also let the build process log all the new properties under the `xml` prefix to the console by using the `EchoProperties` task.

```xml
<project name="SO63816092" default="default">

  <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask" />

  <xmlproperty file="data.xml" prefix="xml" />

  <echoproperties prefix="xml"/>

  <target name="default">
    <xmltask source="display.xml" dest="display.xml" failWithoutMatch="true">
      <replace path="//data/text()" withText="${xml.data}" />
    </xmltask>
  </target>

</project>
```

Using the second approach, while using the following input file `data.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>123456789</data>
```

and the following destination file `display.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>abcdefg</data>
```

I can successfully accomplish what you ask for and get `display.xml` to become:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>123456789</data>
```

Just remember to place the `XmlTask` Java jar in the current classpath for your Ant process and note, that you may need to change the XPath expression, we use, `//data/text()`, to something more refined, should your document structure demand it, because the way, it is now, it would replace the value for *all* `data` elements it finds, throughout the whole `display.xml` document.